# All apps in OS X Mavericks keep crashing

Tags: macos, crash, osx-mavericks

I did a clean installation of OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 a month ago, 
and since then many of my Applications keep crashing multiple times while I’m using them. Twitter, MPlayerX, VLC, Photoshop, Sketch, etc. They crash and show a message like this:

[image]

(The `reason` is different with each app). I’m really getting tired of this problem since I have to start over what I was doing every time.

I own a 15" Macbook Pro 5,4 (Mid-2009). 2.53Ghz Dual Core, 8GBs of Ram.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to repair your installation of 10.9.2 and run disk test?

Comment: @Buscar웃 how to repair it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a hardware issue like defective RAM. Run Apple's [Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) (for Macs made after 2013 [Hardware Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)) to check that.

1. Shut down your computer. Then, press the power button to turn it back on.
2. Press and hold the D key before the gray startup screen appears.
3. It takes a minute or so for AHT to start up and inspect your hardware configuration. When the process is complete, select your language and click the right arrow.
4. Choose which sort of tests to perform.
5. Run test.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too on my MacBook Air, and it turned out to be a failed fan. After replacing it, everything worked fine. So check your Mac, maybe it's also a fan issue.

Comment: Adding a +1 after someone did a -1.  Cooling issues can definitely explain random app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Clean Install was not so clean after all.

Use the cmd-r during start up and follow the instructions to repair/reinstall the Mavericks form the web.

Comment: Is there any way to repair the installation without an internet connection? My connection is not that fast.

Comment: Yes if you have a external disk with OS on it :) you can always try the Disk Utility to repair and also repair the permissions, and if you lucky that could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use: option + command + R to boot straight to the Internet OS download proceedure

There is no other means of obtaining a work-a-round. Either find a broadband connection or visit an Apple Genius Bar where they can perform the reinstall in minutes from their SSD files.

If you Mac has magnetic hard drives then you should perform a full "zeroing-out" of the disk by using Disk Utility first. I recommend doing at least one full pass of zeros.

Unfortunately if you do not own a dvd for the OS (Mavericks nor Mountain Lion have one), Internet access is the only method. When you get the HDD zeroed-out and install a clean OS, immediately make a clone of the HDD for future use (in leu of a DVD).

Good luck!